How to express a value of a variable with a specific place in math.
I’m no mathematician and have found a weird obsession with math and algorithms the past few days. I’ve noticed that in multiplications of 7 if you minus the total by 3 you will get the value in the ones place for the next answer(removing the idea of negatives of course). I also want to find a way to find the correct number for the next answers ten place value but this changes based on 3s so is there a conditional way to say take 21 and if the ones place holder is greater then or equal to 3 then the 10s place must be incremented by 1? I know I am over complicating simple multiplication but I am doing so to learn to express things mathematically. Educate me please, and thank you

When you multiply by $7$, you add successive sevens. For example, $3\times 7=7+7+7$. Adding a seven is the same as adding a ten and subtracting a three. So $7+7 = 7 + 10 - 3=14$, for example.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$7\times(n+1)=7\times n+7=7\times n+10-3.$

So $7\times(n+1)$ has the same $10$s digit as $7\times n$ if $7\times n$ has a ones digit of $0,1,2.$ Otherwise the tens digit is one higher.

Did I understand you right: if you multiply for example 78=56. you  take 6-3 and get 3 which belongs to 79=63?  Instead of multiply by 9 after multiplying by 8 just add 7   adding 7 also means add 10 and deducting 3 which explains your observation

That’s correct how would I express this with simplicity. In a formula is it the same as Thomas said. 7x(n+1)?

Yes the same 7×+10−3
